# Additional .htaccess Rewrite Condition with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

I wish to remove part of a pluggin's URL in Wordpress. I have a standard permalinks setup but have three URLSs with a similar iffy prefix I wish to clean up:

Currently I have

http://domain.com/?pfwk_cats=works

And I require:

http://domain.com/portfolio-works

My current htaccess looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My solution was to add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^portfolio-([^/]*)$ /?pfwk_cats=$1 [L]
```

But it does not kick in? Any ideas? I assuming the Wordpress Rewrite rules are messing it up? Help much appreciated!

Comment: You need to use a RewriteCond, and then a Rewrite Rule. At the moment your using a rule without a condition which won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your custom rule is above the `#BEGIN WordPress` line. The WordPress rewrite rule is a "catch all" so if you put yours below, it will never get there.

Also, don't forget to restart Apache: `service httpd graceful`

~tommy